# Question about Google Calendar API and create multiple Calendars

Tags: list, api, events, calendar, icalendar

I would like to create a script in python that creates events for me for each individual user, I know how to get the list of calendars, but I would like the script to check if there is already a calendar available with that user name and if there isn't one, it creates one, in a way.
Thanks

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from cal_setup import get_calendar_service


currentDateTime = datetime.now()
userfinder = 'Tuxone'
#Create a new calendar 
calendar_name = userfinder
calendar = {
    'summary': calendar_name,
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}

created_calendar = get_calendar_service().calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()

#Print calendar list
# # calendar_list_entry = get_calendar_service().calendarList().get(calendarId=created_calendar['id']).execute()
# # print(calendar_list_entry)

def main():
   # creates one hour event tomorrow 10 AM IST
   service = get_calendar_service()

   d = datetime.now().date()
   tomorrow = datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day, 10)+timedelta(days=1)
   start = tomorrow.isoformat()
   end = (tomorrow + timedelta(hours=1)).isoformat()

   event_result = service.events().insert(calendarId='ici1sgh7untsn7650edoknqblk@group.calendar.google.com',
       body={
           "summary": f'{currentDateTime}',
           "description": 'This is a tutorial example of automating google calendar with python',
           "start": {"dateTime": start, "timeZone": 'Asia/Kolkata'},
           "end": {"dateTime": end, "timeZone": 'Asia/Kolkata'},
       }
   ).execute()

   print("created event")
   print("id: ", event_result['id'])
   print("summary: ", event_result['summary'])
   print("starts at: ", event_result['start']['dateTime'])
   print("ends at: ", event_result['end']['dateTime'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: You already have some code?

Comment: No, only those that example on the google site, to create events and update them